# Communicating with a loop in another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv

So my task is this - I have a GUI thread with sliders of HSV values (among other things), and a worker thread that does all the  OpenCV work and sends processed video images back to GUI thread.

Like it usually is, the OpenCV work is inside of an endless loop. The thing is, half the work is transforming the current video frame according to HSV values sent from GUI sliders. If sent before the loop starts, it works. But not while it's going on, and I need it to work on the fly.

Is there any good way to communicate with that thread and change the HSV values the OpenCV loop is using, or is it a fool's errand? I can think of two solutions, one of which is probably highly inefficient (involves saving values to a file). I'm fairly new to Qt, and I could've easly missed something in the documentation and tutorials.

edit:
Here's how my app works - in GUI thread, user picks a file. A signal with an url is sent to the worker thread, which starts working away. When the user changes HSV values, a signal is sent to change the values from another thread. If the loop hasn't been started, they're received and QDebug shows me that.

edit2:
I might've been thinking about it all wrong. Is there a way for the thread to pull values from the other one? Instead of waiting for them to be sent?

edit3:
kalibracja.cpp, for Micka.

```
int hueMin=0;
int hueMax=180;
int satMin=0;
int satMax=255;
int valMin=15;
int valMax=255;
int satMinDua=133; //tests 

HSV::HSV(QObject * parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    hsvThread  = new QThread;
    hsvThread ->start();
    moveToThread( hsvThread  );
}

HSV::~HSV() //destruktor
{
    hsvThread ->exit(0);
    hsvThread ->wait();
    delete hsvThread ;
}

void HSV::processFrames(QString kalibracja) {

    while(1) {
        cv::VideoCapture kalibrowanyPlik;
        kalibrowanyPlik.open(kalibracja.toStdString());
        int maxFrames = kalibrowanyPlik.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
        for(int i=0; i<maxFrames; i++)
        {
            cv::Mat frame;
            cv::Mat gray;

            //satMin=kontenerHsv->satMin;
            qDebug() << "kalibracja satMin - " << satMin;
            qDebug() << "fdfdf - " << satMinDua;

            kalibrowanyPlik.read(frame);
            cv::cvtColor(frame, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

            QImage image(cvMatToQImage(frame));
            QImage processedImage(cvMatToQImage(gray));

            emit progressChanged(image, processedImage);
            QThread::msleep(750); //so I can read qDebug() messages easly
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::onProgressChagned(QImage image, QImage processedImage) {
    QPixmap processed = QPixmap::fromImage(processedImage);
    processed = processed.scaledToHeight(379);
    ui->labelHsv->clear();
    ui->labelHsv->setPixmap(processed);

    QPixmap original = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
    original = original.scaledToHeight(379);
    ui->labelKalibracja->clear();
    ui->labelKalibracja->setPixmap(original);
}

void HSV::updateHsv(QString hmin, QString hmax, QString smin, QString smax, QString vmin, QString vmax){

    satMinDua=smin.toInt();

}
```

mainwindow.cpp connection

```
HSV *hsv = new HSV;
(.... all kinds of things ....)
void MainWindow::updateHsvValues() {
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(hsv, "updateHsv", Qt::QueuedConnection,
                              Q_ARG(QString, hmin),
                              Q_ARG(QString, hmax),
                              Q_ARG(QString, smin),
                              Q_ARG(QString, smax),
                              Q_ARG(QString, vmin),
                              Q_ARG(QString, vmax));
}
```

Comment: There's no problematic code. This is about ideas - I have no idea what to write. I can send signals to the other thread just fine, but they change HSV values only once (or more like "they're only received after") the OpenCV loop is over.

Comment: to perform the signals/slots (events) in your infinite loop thread, you need to call either `QApplication::processEvents();` within your loop, or use `Qt::DirectConnection` flag in the `connect` of signal/slot (slot will be called by the main thread then, I guess).

Comment: try `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(hsv, "updateHsv", Qt::DirectConnection, ...` instead or add `QApplication::processEvents();` to the infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use QThread in the "wrong" way (by subclassing QThread and using ::run , compare to https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/ ), signal-slot parameter change works in endless loops too:

This is a small sample thread for testing:

```
void MyThread::run()
{
    // start an infinite loop and test whether the sliderchange changes my used parameters

    std::cout << "start infinite loop" << std::endl;
    while(true)
    {
        unsigned long long bigVal = 0;
        int lastVal = mValue;

        std::cout << "start internal processing loop " << std::endl;
        for(unsigned long long i=0; i<1000000000; ++i)
        {
            bigVal += mValue;
            if(lastVal != mValue)
            {
                std::cout << "changed value: " << mValue << std::endl;
                lastVal = mValue;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "end internal processing loop: " << bigVal << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "stop infinite loop" << std::endl;
}
```

with this SLOT, which is connected to the main window slider SIGNAL

```
void MyThread::changeValue(int newVal)
{
    // change a paramter. This is a slot which will be called by a signal.

    // TODO: make this call thread-safe, e.g. by atomic operations, mutual exclusions, RW-Lock, producer-consumer etc...
    std::cout << "change value: " << newVal << std::endl;
    mValue = newVal;
}
```

giving me this result after using the slider:

[image]

this is how the slot was connected:

```
    QObject::connect(mSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), mTestThread, SLOT(changeValue(int)) );
```

---

if the infinite loop is performed as some kind of `workerObject` method which was moved to the thread with `moveToThread`, you can either change the way how the slot is called:

```
QObject::connect(mSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), mTestThread, SLOT(changeValue(int)), Qt::DirectConnection );
```

Never used, but I guess the same should work for invoke:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(hsv, "updateHsv", Qt::DirectConnection, ...
```

(the main thread will call `changeValue` then so the worker thread doesnt need to stop processing to change values => value access should be thread safe!

or you have to process the event queue of that thread:

```
while(true)
{
    [processing]
    QApplication::processEvents(); 
}
```

Comment: I'm not using the threads "the wrong way" (not entirely), and this, as a result, won't work.

Comment: so please post your code how you use your threads... since the "wrong way" is the way that qt suggests... you could try the signal/slot with `Qt::DirectConnection` flag, which should work if you used `moveToThread()` ...

Comment: @Petersaber updated with additional information about event queue with infinite loops

Comment: QApplication::processEvents(); did it! Thank you. I never heard of it before.

Comment: unfortunately it's quite slow, which gave me some problems in another project where I had to process > 100 fps - but nice to hear that it solved your problem! The main event-queue is handled in the main GUI thread, so you've never seen the call in the code. But if you have your own thread with your own event-queue, you have to call it manually.

Comment: Just for clarification: what happened: you've sent all the `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` which writes the requests of `updateHsv` calls into the `event queue` of your thread, but you never gave the thread the time to actually process the calls, which would be done during `processEvents()`.

Comment: If you have a worker object that needs to process events, you shouldn't block the event loop with an infinite loop in the first place.

Comment: @thuga is there any common way to overcome the infinite loop in standard computer vision "camera loop" or video game "rendering loop"?

Comment: @Micka You can replace infinite loops by using timers for example. That way you allow your thread to go back to the event loop and process any pending events. If you really need an infinite loop, then perhaps using slots (or having a thread with a running event loop) is not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible, but you need to be careful.

One of the ways to achieve this would be:

- Create an object that stores the "current" HSV values to be used
- Give a reference (or pointer) to this object to both the GUI thread and the OpenCV thread
- When the GUI wants to "tell" the processing thread to use new values, it published them to that object
- When the processing thread is ready to move on the the next frame (start of loop body), it fetches the values from that object.

You only need to make sure that the set and get methods on that shared object are synchronized, using a mutex for example, to prevent the processing thread from reading half-written values (data races lead to undefined behavior in C++).

Comment: I must be doing something wrong when fetching values from object. I'm sure the values are set properly, but the loop only ever receives the default value (regardless of when or if the values were changed at any point of the program running). How to correctly fetch updated object in the loop?

Comment: Sounds like your threads aren't sharing an object. Although that's not good practice, make that "shared" object a global so you're sure both threads are using the same one (and not copies). Once you get that to work, you can clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution here may be to take advantage of the fact that Qt Signals/Slots work across threads.

Setup the appropriate slots in the processing thread and then signal them from the GUI thread.

---

There are all sorts of interesting questions about whether you signal for every user input, or whether you batch up changes for a moment on the GUI side...

There is some ideas for thread sync in the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-synchronizing.html

Comment: That doesn't work if there's an endless loop in the other thread, unfortunetly